# Dropdown box selected value doesn't exist in the dom, can't grab it with jquery. But it processes through rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm having trouble getting the value of what is currently selected on the page.  The value does exist once rails handles it, but it's not available to me in the dom.  I'm trying use jQuery to activate another class once the value of the dropdown is more than 0.

```
    = form_tag orders_path, id: 'payment-form' do
      - @foo.products.each do |product|
        %li.bullet-item 
          .product.panel
            .small-12
              %h4
                = content_tag_for :li, product, :value => product.id do
                  .row
                    .small-2.columns.switch
                      %input#switchName{:type => "checkbox"}/
                      %label{:for => "switchName"}
                    .small-7.columns
                      = hidden_field_tag("order_products[][product_id]", product.id)
                      = product.name
                      %br
                      .subheader= number_to_currency(product.cost_in_cents.to_f/100)

                    .small-3.columns
                      = select_tag("order_products[][quanity]", options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]), "data-cost-per-unit" => product.cost_in_cents, id: product.name, class: switch)
```

This is what is shown in the javascript console:

```
$('.switch').find('option').val();
"0"
```

Can any rails experts see whats going wrong in my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.switch').find('option').val();
```

This is going to return the value of the *first* `option` element found within that `.switch` element.  This isn't the *selected* option, just the *first* option.  Which is `0`:

```
options_for_select([0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

In order to get the *selected* one, you want the value of the `select` itself:

```
$('.switch').val();
```

(Note that the same behavior will be exhibited here.  If `$('.switch')` finds more than one element then `.val()` will return the value of the *first* one.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, `$('.switch').val();` returns `""`.  in my source, when a value is chosen, I get this: `<select data-cost-per-unit="33" id="test" name="order_products[][quanity]"><option value="0">0</option>`

Comment: @TuxedoTomson: Can you replicate this in a jsFiddle?  If a value is selected, `.val()` on that `select` element really should return the selected value.

Comment: Hmm, i've never really used jsFiddle.  But here is what my form loaded looks like.  http://jsfiddle.net/kupr4wgs/

Comment: @TuxedoTomson: Two problems with that: 1) The `select` doesn't have a class called `switch` so that jQuery selector doesn't find it. 2) The jQuery code is fetching the value when the page *loads*, which *is* `0`. In order to do anything with the value when the selection *changes*, you need to respond to that change. I've updated the jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/kupr4wgs/1/

Comment: Ok, i'm looking into step 2.  But I noticed I sent you the wrong rendered form.  Here it is updated with the switch class.  http://jsfiddle.net/vgoj1dft/

Comment: Thank you, Number 2 helped me a bunch.  I also realized my function was being loaded before jquery, and that was also causing problems.